# jQuery UI Slider not giving "Slide" effect when dragging the pointer from one point to another

Tags: jquery-ui, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jQuery UI slider here.

http://jsfiddle.net/DrR7s/7/

I have animate attribues value as "true". When I place my mouse pointer somewhere on the bar and click there, it is giving a slide visual effect. But if I drag the slider pointer to a different point, I am not getting the animated slide effect which I got in the other case. It looks like its jumping from one point to another. Is there any way I can have the slide effect here too ?

Below is my script:

```
 $(function(){

 $('#slider').slider({
 animate: true,
 step:1,
 min:0,
 max:5

});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise your `max` number, if you put it to `max:100`, it has a smoother dragging. The `max` tells the slider how many points to place on the slider itself. So going from point 0 to point 1 is big jump.

Answer (score 5):

You're using the "Snap to Increments" version of the slider. If you take of the `min, max, step` or just set your `step` to something like .1, you'll get smoother sliding. But if you want to snap to those increments, you can't get smooth dragging.

If you really wanted the smooth sliding *and* the forced incremental values, you could just round the numbers when you go to handle them.